# PHP to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, referenceerror

I'm trying to create a Javascript array using PHP. When I run the PHP code (below), it returns the necessary array.

```
      $counties = 'SELECT * FROM house_price_data_db.county_median_months where county=$1 or county=$2 or county=$3 order by county';
      $result_counties = pg_query_params($dbconn,$counties,array($county1,$county2,$county3)) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
      $county_meds_php = array();
      while($r = pg_fetch_assoc($result_counties)) {
          $county_meds_php[] = $r;
      }
      echo("county_med_month=".json_encode(array_values($county_meds_php), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK).";");

      pg_close($dbconn);?>
```

Here's a snippit of where I'm calling the info in Javascript:

```
county_1="Dublin";
county_2="Galway";
county_meds(county_1,county_2);
function county_meds(a,b){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","county_med_month.php?c_1="+a+"&c_2="+b,false);
   xmlhttp.send()
}
```

Then when I try to call:

```
if(county_med_month.length > 0)
    console.log("The array was created!, the problem was with my JavaScript code!");
```

I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: county_med_month is not defined
```

Advise/suggestions?

Comment: nowhere in your ajax code do you actually capture the response from your script, so exactly as the error says, `country_med_month` never gets defined.

Comment: in the client side, the data is received as text, either you specify the response data type in the AJAX request or you parse it manually

Comment: Paste us in another code box the final javascript code after the PHP has executed (use your browsers built in Inspector tool)

Answer (score 0):

Might be missing something but:

1) Your php response needs to be a valid JSON string

```
echo("county_med_month="
```

Thats not going to make the JSON gods happy.

2) Your php should be send a header

```
header( "Content-type: application/json" );
```

I believe that you are over thinking the solution, try this in PHP.

```
$stuff = ''; // work on stuff later...
$return = array(); // declare variables
$return['county_med_month'] = $stuff // stuff is your content

header( "Content-type: application/json" );
die( json_encode( $return ) );
```

In the Javascript use jQuery to safely abstract the ajax call.

```
$.get( 'php_url.php' , function( response ){

    console.log( response.county_med_month ); // contains you 'stuff'

});
```

Comment: Could you go a little further into how to transform what I have above into AJAX for what I need to do, just I don't quite follow?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to set a javascript variable from php by doing `county_med_month=x`. That's not possible.

On you PHP code, just return the array in json format :

```
  $counties = 'SELECT * FROM house_price_data_db.county_median_months where county=$1 or county=$2 or county=$3 order by county';
  $result_counties = pg_query_params($dbconn,$counties,array($county1,$county2,$county3)) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
  $county_meds_php = array();
  while($r = pg_fetch_assoc($result_counties)) {
      $county_meds_php[] = $r;
  }

  header( "Content-type: application/json" ); // set the header to json
  echo(json_encode($county_meds_php, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)); // this will return json

  pg_close($dbconn);?>
```

Than on javascript, you should parse the content as a json array when the http request is on ready state:

```
county_1="Dublin";
county_2="Galway";

var county_med_month = [];

county_meds(county_1,county_2);

function county_meds(a,b){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    // this method is used to capture the response of the http request
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            county_med_month = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

            // and now you can use the array
            if(county_med_month.length > 0)
                console.log("The array was created!, the problem was with my JavaScript code!");
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","county_med_month.php?c_1="+a+"&c_2="+b,false);
    xmlhttp.send()
}
```

For easier implementation, I would propose to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method.

Comment: I've tried implementing the solution suggested and am getting the following error:  `code`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data `code`

Comment: Try to change `echo(json_encode(array_values($county_meds_php), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));` into `echo(json_encode($county_meds_php, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));`

Comment: Ok that's fixed, the only thing is I'm now getting this when I try to use the array outside of the county_meds() function `ReferenceError: county_med_month is not defined`. Is there a way to make it accessible outside the function?

Comment: Yes, you can declare the variable outside of the function and than just set within the function. I updated the answer.